# Python regex to extract transmission type

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Good Afternoon All,

I have some transmission data here:

```
'6-Speed A/T': 124202,
'CVT Transmission': 46404,
'8-Speed A/T': 39402,
'5-Speed A/T': 34878,
'Automatic': 32708,
'4-Speed A/T': 29160,
'Automatic, 6-Spd': 16533,
'7-Speed A/T': 14310,
'Automatic, CVT': 13880,
'9-Speed A/T': 10348,
'6-Speed M/T': 9406,
'Automatic, 6-Spd w/Overdrive': 7770,
'Automatic, 5-Spd w/Overdrive': 6195,
'Automatic, 4-Spd w/Overdrive': 5277,
'Automatic, 8-Spd': 5274,
'Automatic, 5-Spd': 5247,
'10-Speed A/T': 4285,
'Manual, 6-Spd': 4126,
'5-Speed M/T': 3703,
'Auto, 6-Spd w/SelShft': 3328,
'Auto, 6-Spd SelectShift': 3316,
'Automatic, Xtronic CVT': 3017
```

I am trying to use regex to extract the transmission type. So far I have this code

```py
df['TransmissionType'] = df['Transmission'].str.extract(r'^.*?(A/T|Automatic|Auto|CVT|Manual|M/T)')
```

It is my understanding that this will find one of each of the values in the regex and extract it into a new column.

The problem here is that there is other values that could be in the transmission column that the above code is simply removing, such as `Single-Speed` and `Data not available`.

how can I adjust my regex to capture everything in the transmission column even without knowing what all the values are, if there is a way?

**Edit**

Here is what I have currently:

```py
0             Automatic, 5-Spd w/Overdrive
1                                Automatic
2                           Automatic, CVT
3                                        0
4     Automatic, 6-Spd Allison w/Overdrive
5                                        0
6                     Auto, CVT Manual Spt
7                                        0
8                   Auto, 6-Spd Spt Manual
9                    Auto, 8-Spd Overdrive
10                   Auto, 6-Spd w/SelShft
11           Automatic, 6-Spd w/Sport Mode
12                                       0
13                        Automatic, 6-Spd
14                                       0
15                                       0
16                                       0
17                                       0
18                                       0
19                                       0
```

Dont mind the 0's they are just null values.

When I transform it with the code it looks like this:

```py
df['TransmissionType'] = df['Transmission'].str.extract(r'^.*?(A/T|Automatic|Auto|CVT|Manual|M/T|Single-Speed|Data Not Available)')


    Transmission    TransmissionType
0   Automatic, 5-Spd w/Overdrive    Automatic
1   Automatic   Automatic
2   Automatic, CVT  Automatic
3   0   NaN
4   Automatic, 6-Spd Allison w/Overdrive    Automatic
5   0   NaN
6   Auto, CVT Manual Spt    Auto
7   0   NaN
8   Auto, 6-Spd Spt Manual  Auto
9   Auto, 8-Spd Overdrive   Auto
10  Auto, 6-Spd w/SelShft   Auto
11  Automatic, 6-Spd w/Sport Mode   Automatic
12  0   NaN
13  Automatic, 6-Spd    Automatic
14  0   NaN
15  0   NaN
16  0   NaN
17  0   NaN
18  0   NaN
19  0   NaN
```

Also the CVT transmission will be counted either by itself or as an automatic transmission.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind providing a working test code?

Comment: That depends on the possible formats, you can optionally match the ones starting with a digit and then capture the second part `^'?(?:\d\S*\s)?([A-Z][^\s,':]+)` https://regex101.com/r/vdAgFp/1 But how do you want to differentiate between CVT and Data not available? This will also match whitespace chars https://regex101.com/r/Q8lbfL/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird This seems to be working really well for what I need. I am not sure how to flag it as the answer, but I think this is what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Scott I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the transmission types beforehand (which I hope would be a finite set), you can do something like this -

```
transmission_types = ["A/T", "CVT", "Single-Speed", "Data not available", "Manual"]  # all possible transmission types here maybe ordered?


def get_transmission(text):
    for transmission in transmission_types:
        if transmission in text:
            return transmission
    return "Not Found"

df["transmission"].apply(get_transmission)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
^'?(?:\d\S*\s)?([A-Z][^\s,':]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `'?` Match an optional `'`
- `(?:\d\S*\s)?` Optionally match a digit followed by optional non whitespace chars and then a whitespace char
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z][^\s,':]+` Match a single char A-Z followed by 1+ chars other than  whitespace char `,` `'` `:`
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vdAgFp/1).